# Send data through routing paths in Angular 11

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I don't know what's happending I'm trying to get id through route

this's list.component.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
            <th class="d-none d-sm-block" scope="col">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="table-info" *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4]">
            <th scope="row">Manuel</th>
            <td>manuel@gmail.com</td>
            <td>21/10/2021</td>
            <td class="bnt-group d-none d-sm-block" role="group" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning m-1" (click)="onGoToEdit(item)" >Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning m-1" (click)="onGoToSee(item)" >See</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="onGoToDelete(item)" >Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm adding item[0,1,2,3,4] for each  then it's sending to list.component.ts in attribute (click)

thi's list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state:{
      value: null
    }
  };

  constructor( private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onGoToEdit(item: any): void{
    this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;
    this.router.navigate(['edit', this.navigationExtras]);
  }

  onGoToSee(item: any): void{
    this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;
    this.router.navigate(['details', this.navigationExtras]);
  }  

  onGoToDelete(item: any): void{
    alert("Delete");
  }
}
```

so value item have been stored in this.navigationExtras.state.value

and thi's edit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  
  value = null
  
  

  constructor( private router: Router ) {

    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    this.value = navigation.extras.state;
    console.log(this.value);
  } 

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and from edit.component.ts I'm trying to get value item, but I test from `console.log(this.value)` but from console this is showing `undefined`

why I can get value item?? what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you complicating it?? A simple data pass would be fine i.e., `this.router.navigate(['details', { id: item }]);`

Comment: Study how routers does that https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: yeah! but item is undefined in edit.component.ts

Comment: Edit will recieve id not item and that too via router.paramMap provided that the routing for details url is defined as `details/:id`

Comment: Yeah!! it's working!!! thanks you so much!

Comment: Close the question then ;)

Comment: sorry, but how I can close it?